# Receiving signals from QGraphicsScene with custom items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

i am modeling a chess board using pyqt5 graphicsscene.

th scene is populated with custom QGraphicsItem of 2 types: Case (not movable), Piece (movable)

i overrode the mousepressevent mousemoveevent and mousereleaseevent for the Piece object so that it always land in the center of a case. Not sure if it was the best choice as i could have customized the scene instead .

now i want to receive signals (info on source position, destination position) from the scene or the Piece object, what is a good way to go about that ?

Im new to Qt and not knowing C++ syntax makes it a little hard to follow the official documentation.

```
class Pawn(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x_coord, y_coord, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.x_coord = x_coord
        self.y_coord = y_coord
        self.color = color

        self.setPos(x_coord*30 + 5, y_coord*30 + 5)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

        self.setZValue(2)

        self.sourcePos = QPointF(x_coord*30 + 5, y_coord*30 + 5)
        self.destinationPos = None

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setBrush(QColor(self.color))
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 20, 20)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, 20, 20)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        for item in self.scene().items():
            if isinstance(item, Pawn) and item != self:
                item.setZValue(2)
        self.setZValue(3)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        movePos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        self.setPos(movePos.x() - 15, movePos.y() - 15)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        dropPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        dropCase = None
        for item in self.scene().items(dropPos.x(), dropPos.y(), 0.0001, 0.0001,
                                       Qt.IntersectsItemShape, 
                                       Qt.AscendingOrder):
            if isinstance(item, Case):
                dropCase = item

        if dropCase:
            newP = dropCase.scenePos()
            self.setPos(newP.x()+5, newP.y()+5)
            self.destinationPos = QPointF(newP.x()+5, newP.y()+5)

            """here i want to send the signal that the item changed position
               from self.sourcePos to self.destinationPos"""

            self.sourcePos = self.destinationPos
        else:
            self.setPos(self.sourcePos)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I edited it, didn't post the full code as its too long. the question is just about how to send signals from custom graphicsitem .